# Downloading file from web when the url changes over time

Tags: python, urllib

I have been trying to write a code to download a .zip file using the urllib.request lib.
This is my code:

```py
url = 'http://smartweb.com.br:8080/reports/mancha_cobertura//2019-09-30%20-%202G.zip' 
workspace= r'D:\camila\mancha_2G.zip'

urllib.request.urlretrieve(url_2G, workspace)
```

It works well. However, I need to run it every month, and a part of the file’s name changes according to the date in which it is uploaded to the website.  The part that changes is: “2019-09-30”. Is there a way to tell the code to download this file regardless this part? So the 55th to the 64th character at the url could have any value.

Comment: Is there anywhere on the page that actually displays the filename? If so, you can scrape the website, extract the filename, and then request the download

Comment: you cant't download something when you don't know the url. so you have to scrape the website as @SyntaxVoid said or generate the date from the current system date.